# using VB.net usercontrol in C# project, in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

i have written an asp.net user control in vb.net. now i have a c# web application that i need to use this control in, is there some way to export this user control into a dll or something to be able to resuse it

Comment: do you have asp.net web application project for user controls?

Answer (score 1):

You better move your shared controls to vb.net web application project, then you can reuse that in both vb.net projects and c# projects

Steps:

1. create vb.net project with shared user controls. You can create
   Folder called Controls and put all the user controls there.
2. add above shared project to your c# project and create pre buld event to copy ascx files to c# project like below 
    `copy "$(SolutionDir)SharedControl\*.ascx" "$(ProjectDir)Controls\"`
3. you need to add reference to shared control project
4. register the controls and use it

ASPX

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
```

Comment: +1 @Damith - We have used this approach and liked it. Easier to look at the control's code and to modify to meet new requirements.

Comment: i have tried that before i made this post, but unfortunately it is not working. i have a solution, with 2 asp.net web applications, one in c# and the other one in vb.net, i created a user control in the vb.net project, then draged and dropped it on a webpage in the c# project. and i got this error http://postimg.org/image/renrxhv9f/ , please tell me what i am doing wrong? thank you

Comment: you need to copy ascx files to your project

Answer (score 0):

Publish your vb.net project to some folder. That will generate dll. Drop that dll to your c# project's bin. Drop ascx control to some folder in your c# project. Register tag prefix and you are done.